# Use WinZip command line to zip files including specifc to level folder

Tags: command-line, winzip

I have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
Main/Include
    Include/header.h
    Include/header2.h
Main/Windows
    Windows/code
           /code/code.css
    Windows/bin
           /bin/bar.txt
Main/Mac
    Mac/code
           /code/code.css
    Mac/bin
           /bin/bar.txt
```

I want to zip everything up EXCEPT the Mac directory. So essentially I want to have Include and Windows/* in the zip folder like this:

.zip ---

```
code
   code/code.css
bar
   bin/bar.txt
Include
   Include/header.h
   Include/header2.h
```

My issue is I cannot seem to figure out how to get winzip to zip the include folder w/out include the mac (by doing Main/*)

This is what I am running:

```
c:\\progra~2\\winzip\\wzzip.exe -rp zip_win.zip Main\Include\\* Main\Windows\\*
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Zip Main/Include then add Main/Windows to it.  OR Move Main/Mac somewhere else, then zip everything left behind, then put Main/Mac back where you found it.

Comment: I want to retain the Include folder, so doing Main/Include/* doesn't quite work because it zips all the files, but doesn't retain the structure. I am trying to avoid moving Main/Mac